# Ruby on Rails join, where without losing associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using ruby 2.1.5 on rails 4.2 and got a little problem
I got Users and with a has many relation logins.

```
@users = User.joins(:logins).where("country LIKE ?", "%#{params[:searchc]}%").uniq
```

I want to find Users depending on the logins but i cant figure out a good solution to show the associated objects in my view too.
With the join i lose the associated logins and only the found ones are left but i need all.

```
@users.includes(:logins).each
```

is the problem.
Start a new load login ( @users.first.logins) for each user is very slow...

Edit: 
Well i got a work around:

```
@users = User.joins("JOIN logins ON (logins.user_id = users.id AND logins.country LIKE '#{params[:searchc]}')", ).uniq.includes(:logins)
```

If there is a better solution tell me pls

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. Do you want to get all users (with `where` condition) and display logins of each one?

Comment: its a bit hard to explain in english sry ;) I want to find users! But the search depends on the logins and after the join the @users.first.logins only return the logins with a hit and not all logins which belong to the user.

Comment: I think there is a way to do this in one line and without reloading all logins from a user

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) instead of `joins`. It is also known as N+1 query

```
@users = User.includes(:logins).where("country LIKE ?", "%#{params[:searchc]}%").uniq
```

Comment: Well i tried it but: Unknown column 'country' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

you will need to qualify where country is,  so assuming it is in your logins table, something like this

```
  @users = User.joins(:logins).("logins.country LIKE ?", "%#{params[:searchc]}%").uniq
```

Comment: Thats not my problem. I can find all users with the right country but after that i cant use, the already loaded, logins anymore because only the ones with country = params[:searchc] are left